# Unable to send text from html file to c file

Tags: html, c, cgi

I'm trying to write a very basic html file and a cgi script. The HTML file will have one text box and a button. The button will send the contents of the text box to a cgi file (without the content of the text box showing up in the url) which will simply print out the contents of the text box. Instead of that happening, my cgi file simply prints out '-|' regardless of what I put in the text box.

Here is my .html file:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>template webpage</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white" text="black">

  <form action="http://cgi.cs.mcgill.ca/~eross12/cgi-bin/results.cgi" method="GETS">
    <div><label>Input: <input name="data" size="5"></label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Send!"></div>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my c file that is supposed to be receiving the text from the html file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
  char *data;
  char *input;
  printf("%s%c%c\n","Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);
  printf("<TITLE>Received Data</TITLE>\n");
  printf("<H3>Received Data</H3>\n");
  data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
  if(data == NULL)
    printf("<P>Error! Error in passing data from form to script.");
  else
  {
    fgets(input,256,stdin);
   printf("<P>The input is: \"%s\"",input);
  }
 return 0;
}
```

From what I've read online I believe that if I want to use fgets my 'method' in my form should be POST instead of GETS but if I make that change I get an internal server error when I click on my button. If anyone could tell me what changes I need to make I would be extremely grateful! Alternatively, if you could show me a basic .html file and basic c script that does what I'm describing that would also be wonderful! I unfortunately can't use javascript or PHP or various other tools that I've seen people recommend in response to other questions on stackoverflow.

P.S. If you want to see my .html file in action, click [here](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~eross12/input1.html) and if you want to see it with the method set to POST instead of GETS click [here](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~eross12/input2.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with the code is that `input` is uninitialized.

That's why you are getting an internal server error when using `POST`.

Just replace `char *input;` with `char *input = (char*)malloc(1000);`  and it should work.

Comment: Hey sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I asked this question on behalf of a friend and they never said that they got a response! Your solution worked perfectly!
I'm surprised it was such a simple mistake considering that he used code provided by his professor, but it's often the little things that throw us for a loop!
Anyway, thanks again for your help!